# How to reset COMP_WORDBREAKS without affecting other completion script?

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete, bash-completion

There is something confuse me when I implement a bash auto-completion function which I'll put it in **/etc/bash_completion.d/**

In order to achieve some feature, I want to remove the word break characters colon (`:`) from variable `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` and add a slash (`/`) at begin of `$COMP_WORDBREAKS`.

```
COMP_WORDBREAKS=" /'><=;|&("
_mytool()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    compopt -o nospace

    # my implement here

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen ..........my_implement......... -- $cur) )
}
complete -F _mytool mytool
```

However, I can't reset `COMP_WORDBREAKS` directly because the value is shared with other completion scripts.  By the time the completion function gets called, variable `COMP_WORDS` array has already been populated, so locally changes `COMP_WORDBREAKS` have no effect.

Is there any solution for changing `COMP_WORDBREAKS` in one completion script and no effect to other script?

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.10(1)-release
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Modifying `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` in your completion script is not the recommended way (as it is a global variable and it could affect the behavior of other completion scripts - for example ssh).

However, bash completion offers some helper methods which you can use to achieve your goal.

The recommended way to handle non-word-breaking characters in completion words is by using the two helper methods:

- `_get_comp_words_by_ref` with the `-n EXCLUDE` option

  - gets the word-to-complete without considering the characters in EXCLUDE as word breaks
- `__ltrim_colon_completions`

  - removes colon containing prefix from COMPREPLY items 
    (a workaround for http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ - E13)

So, here is a basic example of how to a handle a colon (:) in completion words:

```sh
_mytool()
{
    local cur
    _get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur

    # my implementation here

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen ..........my_implement......... -- $cur) )

    __ltrim_colon_completions "$cur"
}
complete -F _mytool mytool
```

As a final tip, the helper methods are located in `/etc/bash_completion`. Take a look inside to read a detailed description of each method and to discover more helper methods.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really useful for my rake task completions in Ruby on Rails! Also, thanks for pointing out section E13 in the docs.

Comment: this only worked properly, when I put this line `cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"` before `_get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur` also good to know, if you use the prev too, you can add it at the end `_get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur prev`

Comment: When I have ambiguous completions and hit tab twice I get incorrect suggestions based on what I have typed when I use this solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479216/how-to-give-correct-suggestions-to-tab-complete-when-my-words-contains-colons

Comment: Content of `/etc/bash_completion` tells in the heading comment for `__ltrim_colon_completions`: "The preferred solution is to remove the colon (:) from COMP_WORDBREAKS in your .bashrc"

Comment: How does ssh's bash completion break, if COMP_WORDBREAKS is trimed? I suppose ssh's autocompletion could be fixed to work in both cases.

Comment: With the solution, completion works somewhat differently: Prefix ending with : is trimmed off from shown completions.

Comment: Instead of using `_get_comp_words_by_ref` you could use `_init_completion -n :`, but you have to declare more local variables then.

Comment: to add to @jarno 

`local cur prev words cword`
then `_init_completion -n :`

and you get a COMP_WORDS array in `words` without the colon breaking words

Comment: `_init_completion` is nicer, but it still requires `__ltrim_colon_completions` (otherwise the completion includes extra text)