# Bash completion after equals does not work on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, bash-completion

On my Ubuntu 14.04.3 machine with enabled bash completion (through `. /etc/bash_completion` in ~/.bashrc), I do not get directory-content completion for `cmd --param=<TAB>`, i.e., nothing is happening when pressing . When I start a pristine bash (e.g. through `env -i bash --norc`), it works as expected -- but then no programmable completion is available. I found [Bash completion for path in argument (with equals sign present)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365372/bash-completion-for-path-in-argument-with-equals-sign-present) which talks about a similar issue but 1) the respective npm script is not existing on my machine and 2) even removing all files from /etc/bash_completion.d does not fix the problem. What can I do to get proper completion?

I found one halfhearted fix by running `complete -r -D` which prevents bash from trying to complete new commands. This enables completion after equals again, but stops completion, for example, for killall.

Comment: Does `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` include an `=`? If not, try `COMP_WORDBREAKS+==` and see if completion does what you expect.

Comment: The content of $COMP_WORDBREAKS is `"'><=;|&(:`. Removing or adding `=` does not seem to change the behavior wrt. completion after `=`, unfortunately.

Comment: Run `complete -p cmd` and see if there's a compspec defined for your *cmd*.

Comment: No, there is no specific compspec defined, it does not complete properly for any command (last time I used `ljkasdfjler --asdlk=<TAB>` ;) )

Answer (score 0):

While I do not understand what you mean by "stops completion after killall", I believe there is a workaround.

I found it [here](http://lists.opensuse.org/archive/opensuse-bugs/2013-12/msg02700.html). It involves overriding a broken bash completion function. Copy-pasting here for the record. The workaround is to **add the following to your `.bashrc`**:

```
_completion_loader () {
  local dir=/usr/share/bash-completion/completions
  local cmd="${1##*/}"
  . "${dir}/${cmd}" &>/dev/null && return 124
  complete -o default -o bashdefault "${cmd}" &>/dev/null && return 124
}
```

I am uncertain whether the actual reported [bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=851908) is fixed in bash: the comments in the bug report are unclear and mention a couple more problems. For the record, my bash is version 4.2.46(1)-release (Redhat EL 7) which does have this bug.