# How do I tell bash autocompletion that the colon separates the switch from the value?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a program which uses switches in the form:

```
/path/to/binary --foo:on|off --bar:opt1|opt2|opt3 --path:filename
```

I have been able to create a bash autocompletion file which adds the `--foo` or `--bar` switches, but I can't seem to add detection on the *previous* used switch to complete the `on|off` because the colon is not recognised by bash as a split character between the switch and its value. Bash autocompletion works fine if I make it accept `--foo on|off` using a space, but unfortunately the program requires the colon and the completion with the space will be incorrect.

Can this be fixed modifying somehow `COMP_WORDBREAKS`? I can't see any example in the man page to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your completion should act as though `binary` takes not an option `--foo` with an argument of `on` or `off`, but two separate options `--foo:on` and `--foo:off`, because that's exactly what `binary` takes.

For non-constant options, such as your `--path:foo/bar` example, perhaps something like

```
cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

case $cur in
    --path:*)
      IFS=: read opt partialFile
      for f in $(compgen -f $partialFile); do
          COMPREPLY+=( "--path:$f" )
      done
      ;;
```

I realize this won't work well with file names containing whitespace or other special characters, but then I'm not sure how programmable completion deals with them in the first place.

Comment: That would work for constant values, unfortunately some switches like ``--path:foo/bar`` accept a path and I can't use ``compgen -f ``.

Comment: Thanks, along with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528695/how-to-reset-comp-wordbreaks-without-effecting-other-completion-script I managed to match colons inside the ``case`` and cut the rest of ``$cur`` for path completion.