# bash complete with colon

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm trying to add auto-complete function to `mytool` command with following `_mytool` complete function:

```
_mytool()
{
  local cur
  _get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur

  # my implementation here
  COMPREPLY=()   # Array variable storing the possible completions.
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

  if [[ $cur = -* ]]; then
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W '-a:first -a:second' -- $cur) )
  fi

  __ltrim_colon_completions "$cur"
}
complete -F _mytool mytool
```

Because there is ":" in my `COMPREPLY`, I try to make it work by using `_get_comp_words_by_ref` and `__ltrim_colon_completions` function, which is learnt from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528695/how-to-reset-comp-wordbreaks-without-effecting-other-completion-script/12495480)

But it still not work when type:

```
$mytool -a:[TAB]
```

there is no auto-complete at all. I was expecting bash will print the following completion for me:

```
-a:first -a:second
```

my bash version:

```
4.3.46(1)-release
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I'm coming here with the same issue - it seems that the _get_comp_words_by_ref and __ltrim_colon_completions functions still have no documentation anywhere that I can find - so it's unclear how you're supposed to use them. I'm commenting in the hopes that your question becomes more visible.

Comment: @Lou just stumbled on this accidentally. `__get_comp_words_by_ref` seems to be defined in the `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion` script (line 36) loaded via your `.bashrc`. The function is preceded by a nice header explaining usage and available flags.