# Bash Command-Line Tab Completion Colon Character

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have successfully implemented bash completions for my custom commands when the parameters contained no special characters in them, with the compgen mechanism:

```
    current=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    all=$(_get_all_items)
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$all" -- $current) )
    ...
    complete -F _prog_compl prog
```

I use the same approach to complete items which start with a colon character: `:first`, `:second`, ... But it fails to show me / autocomplete them. I tried escaping colons with backslashes which didn't work either. *How should I escape colons in completion?*

The items are starting with colon, let's say: `:first`, `:second`. If I write progname and start with a colon like this:

```
$ progname :<Tab here after colon>
```

I see **no completion** but two colons ("::") - one of them automatically added to the line I type. If I convert the colon to an ordinary character (let's say 'b') I get completion exactly like I want: `bfirst`, `bsecond`...

**It is relevant to note that when I press tab it places another ":" next to my previously inserted colon and it becomes "::".**

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.10(2)-release (i486-slackware-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Additionally, I have made some experiments in the shell which yield:

```
$ compgen -W ":aaaa5 :gb2 :cd3" -- ":"
:aaaa5
:gb2
:cd3
```

Yet it strangely puts another ":" to my sole ":" and makes it "::" after I type : on the command line.

```
$ complete
complete -F _alp_compl alp.sh
complete -o nospace -F __dbus_send dbus-send
complete -F _myprog_compl myprog
complete -o nospace -F __gdbus gdbus
complete -o nospace -F __gsettings gsettings
```

Comment: Care to provide how you execute your `complete` command as well?

Comment: Do you really get nothing or do you get offered filename completion?

Comment: Updated question for your answers @konsolebox and Ethan.

Comment: Do you have other completions which use colon for something?  Typical candidates are `tar` and `ssh` which use remote file names with colons in them.  There may even be hard-coded special cases for this in Bash itself.

Comment: I added complete output on my shell. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After consulting *help-bash@gnu.org* I got an answer:

> The colon breaks words for the completion system (look at the
>   description of the COMP_WORDBREAKS shell variable), so when you type
>
> progname :[TAB]
>
> the completion system gets an empty word to complete.  If all of the
>   possible completions have `:' as the longest common prefix, then the
>   completion system will insert the colon into the line.

And my COMP_WORDBREAKS search yield me an answer from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805412/bash-completion-for-maven-escapes-colon/12495727#12495727).

After fixing (my missing) /etc/bash_completion file from [debian bash completion page](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/), now, my colon-initiated completion is working as my will.