# Bash Completion on OS X With Colons

Tags: php, bash, phar, bash-completion

I'm the creator and maintainer of a PHP based command line application for developers.  My command's syntax follows the norms of other PHP command line applications, and looks like this

```
pestle.phar some:command:name ...arguments and options here...
pestle.phar some:command      ...arguments and options here...
```

That is -- colons are used in the command name. This presented problems when I tried using the stock autocomplete features of bash.

Thanks to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362968/bash-command-line-tab-completion-colon-character) other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805412/bash-completion-for-maven-escapes-colon/12495727#12495727) I was able to determine this was bash treating the `:` as a word separator, and that the bash-completion project (`brew install bash-completion`) could help.  I've been able to pull a script together that sort of works -- but I'm stuck on a few things and don't understand the system well enough to diagnose on my own.  Also, my bash scripting skills are rusty.

Here's a sample of something that sort of works.

```
#File: /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/pestle-autocomplete.sh
#!/bin/bash

_commandList ()
{
    echo "codecept:convert-selenium-id-for-codecept"
    echo "magento2:check-templates"
    echo "magento2:generate:acl"
    #.. other comand names..
    return 0;
}

_pestleAutocomplete ()
{
    local cur
    local all
    _get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur
    all=$(_commandList)
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$all" $cur) )
    __ltrim_colon_completions "$cur"
    return 0
}
complete -F _pestleAutocomplete -o filenames pestle.phar
```

If I type `$ pestle.phar mag` and then hit tab, the follow is output in my shell

```
$ pestle.phar magento2\:
```

That is, `magento2:` auto completes, but the `:` is escaped with a slash.  If I complete a command name, this "works", but looks a little funny.  So question 1 -- how do I get rid of that slash, and where's it coming from.

Second -- I don't understand what the `__ltrim_colon_completions` command does.  In the examples I've seen, its usually used something like

```
_mytool()
{
    local cur
    _get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur

    # my implementation here

    __ltrim_colon_completions "$cur"
}
complete -F _mytool mytool
```

However, to my naive eyes -- that seems to be doing nothing.  Its an extraneous call at the end of of the script using a local variable.  I assume it changes some state in the bash-completion system, but again, my knowledge there is incomplete.  I'm not sure if its related to my escaping problem.

If anyone here has a concrete answer, or can get me pointed in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. OS X 10.11, El Cap, stock bash -- if it matters.

Comment: I presume that changing `COMP_WORDBREAKS` globally is not an option in case your users already rely on it?  Is that why you've not accepted the answer below?  Please let us know if you found a solution.

Comment: Oh god -- I started re-reading this question and -- I don't even know what I was asking back then? I know I "solved" this problem by letting someone smart fix the the autocomplete in my GitHub project (https://github.com/astorm/pestle) but I have no idea what they did or how it works or how anything works anymore, and I'm so sorry because I've been in your exact position before @keeely, looking at old Stack Overflow questions and wondering why they're abandoned, and I guess I've become that person now. I hope you can forgive me.

Comment: no probs and thanks for replying but it will be very useful if you can point me to the pestle commit that fixed it.

Comment: @keely Here's the two files that make up pestle's auto-commits -- git blame backwards through history to see how they've evolved. (we may have just sidestepped this issue, so no promises)  Good luck! https://github.com/astorm/pestle/blob/master/pestle-autocomplete.sh https://github.com/astorm/pestle/blob/master/gen-event-list.sh

Comment: I'm trying to fix the same problem nearly two years later - I'd be grateful if you did manage to break down the solution that ultimately fixed your problem and post it as an answer. I'm looking at your code now and I admit I'm not too clear from looking what it does or how it fixes the colon issue.

Comment: @Lou Sadly I've lost the context of all this to middle aged memory -- but I believe a contributor to my repo came along and made all this work. You might have luck fishing into the histories of the above `astorm/pestle` commits.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to adjust the `COMP_WORDBREAKS` variable in a way that makes the colon behave differently from it's normal completion behavior:

```
COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//:}
```

Removing `:` from that value is enough to make the colon not special to completion (which may or may not be what you are wanting). I suspect that it gets the backslash `\:` in front of it is because of the way you have excluded it with `_get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur`. You can also quote the colon with a backslash to achieve the same result temporarily.

> Filename completion (and word completion in general) may appear to
>   behave improperly if there is a colon in the word to be completed.
>
> The colon is special to readline's word completion code:  it is one of
>   the characters that breaks words for the completer.  Readline uses
>   these characters in sort of the same way that bash uses `$IFS:` as they
>   break or separate the words the completion code hands to the
>   application-specific or default word completion functions.  The
>   original intent was to make it easy to edit colon-separated lists
>   (such as `$PATH` in bash) in various applications using readline for
>   input.
>
> This is complicated by the fact that some versions of the popular
>   `bash-completion' programmable completion package have problems with
>   the default completion behavior in the presence of colons.
>
> The current set of completion word break characters is available in
>   bash as the value of the `COMP_WORDBREAKS` variable.  Removing `:' from
>   that value is enough to make the colon not special to completion.

**`__ltrim_colon_completions`**

This function basically just trims the completion so that the word returned is only the prefix ( or whatever is remaining to the left of the last colon on the right ). An example would be a command such as `hello:world` and I started typing in `he` and pressed <kbd>TAB</kbd>, the `hello:` portion is what will be returned. The function is precisely this:

```
# Define preload__ltrim_colon_completions="false", if the function
# __perf__ltrim_colon_completions() is required instead.
preload__ltrim_colon_completions="true"

if [ $preload__ltrim_colon_completions = "true" ]; then
    type __ltrim_colon_completions &>/dev/null ||
    preload__ltrim_colon_completions="false"
fi
[ $preload__ltrim_colon_completions = "true" ] ||
__perf___ltrim_colon_completions()
{
    if [[ "$1" == *:* && "$COMP_WORDBREAKS" == *:* ]]; then
        # Remove colon-word prefix from COMPREPLY items
        local colon_word=${1%"${1##*:}"}
        local i=${#COMPREPLY[*]}
        while [[ $((--i)) -ge 0 ]]; do
            COMPREPLY[$i]=${COMPREPLY[$i]#"$colon_word"}
            echo $COMPREPLY[$i]
        done
        echo $colon_word
    fi
}
```

Some of the other variables in the completion code can be set to handle words differently depending on the application; maybe try the method at the very top and if that isn't what you're looking for then maybe browse through [the code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/perf-completion.sh) responsible for controlling it.